# Прошить AT89S52 программатором на FT2232D

Tags: микроконтроллеры

Добрый день!
Есть Ubuntu 16.04 + универсальный модуль на базе FTDI(FT2232D).
Интересует вопрос возможности прошивки микроконтроллера AT89S52 с помощью программатора на FT2232D. 
Подскажите софт для прошивки плз,если таковой имеется.

Comment: `avrdude` в режиме `FTDI bitbang`